# Можно ли вывести универсальный скрипт для определения системы управления пакетами?

Tags: linux, bash, deb, rpm

Есть приложение в виде .deb и .rpm пакета.
Хотелось найти бы какой-нибудь способ определить систему управления пакетами(dpkg или rpm) без перебора всех возможных ОС с их версиями, что бы в последствии добавить это в скрипт.
Первое что пришло на ум это что то типо такого:

```
if command -v rpm &> /dev/null; then
    rpm -i ./my_app.rpm
fi

if command -v dpkg &> /dev/null; then
    dpkg -i ./my_app.deb
fi
```

Но как то мне это не нравится, может есть варианты по надёжнее?

Comment: AppImage, Flatpak, Snap…

Comment: @Alexey Ten
Пока этих двоих достаточно

Comment: pacman, nix... А ещё есть странные дистрибутивы вроде Alt Linux, у которого есть dpkg и apt, а пакеты всё равно rpm

Comment: @andreymal да и в убунту никто не мешает поставить `rpm` (как приложение). В общем гадать по наличию исполняемого файла так себе идея. Я бы начал с `lsb_release --id --short`, но тут тоже есть много весёлого, типа десятка основанных на ubuntu дистрибутивах в которых будет написано `kali`, `elementary` и т.п.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/459425 вот похожий вопрос

Comment: можно глянуть как это реализовано в утилите [pacapt](https://github.com/icy/pacapt) а конкретнее в этом сценарии -  [pacapt/lib/00_core.sh](https://github.com/icy/pacapt/blob/ng/lib/00_core.sh)

Comment: @Zt. А вот это интересно, спасибо. 
В какой-то момент идет жесткий перебор всех пакетных менеджеров)
Даже любопытно как он отработает с Alt linux, где установщик  apt-get ставит rpm пакеты.

Comment: у меня на арче стоят программы apt, dpkg, yum, rpm....)

Comment: Я так понимаю, кто-то хочет написать свою штуку для установки прог и правки конфигов и чтобы "само"? Посмотри в сторону `ansible`.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

```
which apt &> /dev/null && apt install -y $something
which yum &> /dev/null && yum install -y $something
...
```

Comment: На вышеупомянутом Alt Linux не сработает

Answer (score 1):

Пробуй

```
pkcon install-local file.deb
```